# Unable to set mic sampling rate with Alsa on Raspbian

Tags: python, raspbian, alsa

I am new to Alsa on Raspbian and I need my mic to give 16khz sampling rate for porcupine/snowboy hotword detection. However, I've not been able to find a single way to do so. I need to do this for my Final year project, and I've been stuck on it for a week or so, but I can't do anything. Same mic/soundcard works fine with windows (porcupine), but it gives "errno -9997 invalid sample rate" with Raspbian.

EDITED CODE:

```
import snowboydecoder
import sys
import signal

interrupted = False


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global interrupted
    interrupted = True


def interrupt_callback():
    global interrupted
    return interrupted

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("Error: need to specify model name")
    print("Usage: python demo.py your.model")
    sys.exit(-1)

model = sys.argv[1]

# capture SIGINT signal, e.g., Ctrl+C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

detector = snowboydecoder.HotwordDetector(model, sensitivity=0.5)
print('Listening... Press Ctrl+C to exit')

# main loop
detector.start(detected_callback=snowboydecoder.play_audio_file,
               interrupt_check=interrupt_callback,
               sleep_time=0.03)

detector.terminate()
```

here is my error:

```
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
    Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
    Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "demo.py", line 27, in <module>
        detector = snowboydecoder.HotwordDetector(model, sensitivity=0.5)
      File "/home/pi/Downloads/snowboy/snowboydecoder.py", line 115, in __init__
        stream_callback=audio_callback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
        stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
        self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
    IOError: [Errno -9997] Invalid sample rate
```

The problem is most probably with alsa but am not able to convert rate on the fly to 16khz. If anyone knows how to do that that'll be of great help.

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). **Please edit your post accordingly**, that way might have more luck getting answers

Comment: @5th My apologies, Edited it.